# Post operation not working with Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm learning Node.JS with Angular 4. I build a sample Node API for simple GET/POST request. My GET operation works fine and I am able to fetch data in Angular. My OST operation isn't getting called at all from Angular. If I use Postman, I'm able to call POST successfully and data also gets inserted in database.

Here is my sample code for Node POST:

```
app.post('/groups', function (req, res, next){


res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT");

console.log('Request received with body' + req.body);
//DEV AWS MySQL
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                      host     : 'xxxxxxx',
                      user     : 'xxxxxxx',
                      password : 'xxxxxxx',
                      database : 'xxxxxxx',
                      port     : 3306
});
connection.connect();

connection.query('CALL storedprocedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [req.body.group_avatar_image,req.body.name,req.body.display_name,req.body.unique_id,req.body.description,req.body.adzone], function (err, results, fields){

    if (err)
        res.send(results);

    //res.status(201).send("Groups created successfully");
    res.status(201).send(results[0]);
});
```

This works fine with Postman and I get 201.

Here is my Angular 4 code:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Group } from './group';

@Injectable()
export class GroupsService{

    private _GroupsUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/groups';
    constructor(private _http: Http){};

    getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        //headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding");
        let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headers,  url:this._GroupsUrl  });    

        //debugger;
        return this._http.get(this._GroupsUrl)
                .map((Response: Response) => <Group[]>Response.json()[0])
                //.do(data => console.log ('ALL: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    CreateGroup(GroupM): Observable<string>{

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        //let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headers, body:JSON.stringify(GroupM),  url:this._GroupsUrl  });    
        let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post});    

        console.log('Calling ' + this._GroupsUrl + ' with body as :' + JSON.stringify(GroupM) + ' and request options are : ' + JSON.stringify(options));

        var req = new Request(options.merge({
        url: this._GroupsUrl
        }));

        debugger;
        //return this._http.post(this._GroupsUrl,GroupM)
        return this._http.post(req.url,JSON.stringify(GroupM),options)
                     .map(res => res.json())
                     .do(data => console.log ('ALL: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
                     .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error:Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error');
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of `this._http`? What does the browser console/network show when you execute this code?

Comment: Nothing except my console.log of information...i don't see POST call in network tab at all. I tried following;         let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body:JSON.stringify(GroupM), method:"post" });   
return this._http.post(this._GroupsUrl,JSON.stringify(GroupM),{headers: headers})
                    .map((Response: Response) => <string>Response.json()[0])
                    .do(data => console.log('Service response: ' + data))
                    .catch(this.handleError);

Comment: so you do see `console.log('Calling ' + this._GroupsUrl + ' with Options :' + options.headers.toJSON());`?

Comment: have you tried setting a `debugger;`?

Comment: what does `console.log(this._http.post)` show?

Comment: when i attach debugger, it calls internally http.prototype.post and inside that it call requestOption and URL, method becomes null. Now i know why i don't see it in network tab but don't understand why this is happening

Comment: Where is `_GroupsUrl` coming from? Perhaps you are losing your reference to it within the function that is making the request. Can you show us where `_GroupsUrl` is being set? Also, try assigning `_GroupsUrl` to a variable and then passing it in.

Comment: _GroupsUrl is local variable. Here is complete denition of my class

Comment: URL http method get overwritten in  Http.prototype.post = function (url, body, options) {
        return this.request(new Request(mergeOptions(this._defaultOptions.merge(new RequestOptions({ body: body })), options, RequestMethod.Post, url)));
    }; from http.es5.js

Comment: From what you are detailing, the problem almost certainly is within the frontend service but I can not see any obvious errors. Please update the question with the whole angular service.

Comment: i put same request on angular github and they are saying it seems like CORS issue but i don't see any errors

Comment: @jatin : please add component code from where u are actually calling this service.

Comment: Are you actually subscribing to your request? If you do not subscribe, the call isn't made. As you do get some logging in your console, I'm not sure this is the case, but still, I have to ask ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally able to resolve it using promise and it resolves the issue. Not sure what exactly is the issue with observable.

```
>  CreateGroup(GroupObj:Group) : Promise<Group>{
        return this._http
                .post(this._GroupsUrl,JSON.stringify(GroupObj),{headers: this.headers})
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => res.json().data as Group)
                .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you replace `.catch(this.handleError);` with `.catch(e => this.handleError(e));` the current code is a ticking timebomb where any use of `this` added to the `handleError` method will cause the app to fail surprisingly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do yourself a favour and wrap Angular's `Http` service so that you don't have to manually add an auth token and headers for every request. Here's a simple implementation which you can build on:

First of all let's create a `Cookies` service which will act as a fallback where `localStorage` isn't supported:

```
@Injectable()

export class Cookies {

  public static getItem(sKey) {

    if (!sKey) {
      return null;
    }

    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  }

  public static setItem(sKey?, sValue?, vEnd?, sPath?, sDomain?, bSecure?) {

    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) {
      return false;
    }

    let sExpires = '';

    if (vEnd) {

      switch (vEnd.constructor) {

        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;

        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;

        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");

    return true;
  }

  public static removeItem(sKey, sPath?, sDomain?) {

    if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) {
      return false;
    }

    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");

    return true;
  }

  public static hasItem(sKey) {

    if (!sKey) {
      return false;
    }

    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  }

  public static keys() {

    let aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);

    for (let nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) {
      aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]);
    }

    return aKeys;
  }
}
```

Then a storage logger which keeps track of things added to the storage (useful for updating the auth token for every request when it changes):

```
import {Cookies} from '@services/cookies.service';

@Injectable()

export class StorageLogger {

  private logger = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  public logger$ = this.logger.asObservable();

  set(key: string, value: any): void {

    try {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
    catch(err) {
      Cookies.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

    this.get(key);
  }

  get(key: string) {

    let item: any;

    try {
      item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    }
    catch(err) {
      item = JSON.parse(Cookies.getItem(key));
    }

    this.logger.next({value: item, key: key});
  }

  remove(keys: string[]) {

    try {

      for (const key of keys) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
        this.logger.next({value: null, key: key});
      }
    }
    catch(err) {

      for (const key of keys) {
        Cookies.removeItem(key);
        this.logger.next({value: null, key: key});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you want to wrap angular's `Http`:

```
@Injectable()

/* Wrapper for Angular's Http class, let's us provide headers and other things on every request */
export class HttpClient implements OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private storageLogger: StorageLogger
  ) {

    this.getToken();

    this.storageSubscription = this.storageLogger.logger$.subscribe(
      (action: any) => {

        if (action && action.key === tokenIdKey) {
          this.getToken();
        }
      }
    );
  }

  private storageSubscription: Subscription;
  private token: string;

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.storageSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  getToken(): void {

    try {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem(tokenIdKey);
    }
    catch(error) {
      this.token = Cookies.getItem(tokenIdKey);
    }
  }

  convertJSONtoParams(json: any): URLSearchParams {

    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    for (const key in json) {

      if (json.hasOwnProperty(key) && json[key]) {

        if (json[key].constructor === Array && !json[key].length) {
          continue;
        }
        else {
          params.set(key, json[key]);
        }
      }
    }

    return params;
  }

  getRequestOptions(params?: any): RequestOptions {

    const headers = new Headers();

    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

    return new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers,
      search: params ? this.convertJSONtoParams(params) : null
    });
  }

  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers): void {
    headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
  }

  checkResponseStatus(err: any) {

    if (err.status === 401) {

      // If we want we can redirect to login here or something else
    }

    return Observable.of(err);
  }

  get(url: string, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.get(host + url, options).catch((err: Response) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }

  post(url: string, data: any, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.post(host + url, data, options).catch((err: Response) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }

  put(url: string, data: any, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.put(host + url, data, options).catch((err: Response) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }

  delete(url: string, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.delete(host + url, options).catch((err: Response) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }

  patch(url: string, data: any, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.patch(host + url, data, options).catch((err: Response) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }

  head(url: string, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.head(host + url, options).catch((err) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }

  options(url: string, params?: any): Observable<Response> {

    const options: RequestOptions = this.getRequestOptions(params);

    return this.http.options(host + url, options).catch((err: Response) => this.checkResponseStatus(err));
  }
}
```

And finally you should also add a generic api service which you will call, instead of creating a new service for every part of your application. This will save you a lot of code and effort. Here it is:

```
import {IResponse} from '@interfaces/http/response.interface';
import {HttpClient} from '@services/http/http-client.service';

@Injectable()

export class AppApi {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get(url: string, params?: any): Observable<IResponse> {

    return this.http.get(url, params)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IResponse)
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }
    );
  }

  post(url: string, data: any, params?: any) {

    return this.http.post(url, data, params)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IResponse)
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }
    );
  }

  put(url: string, data: any, params?: any) {

    return this.http.put(url, data, params)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IResponse)
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }
    );
  }

  delete(url: string, params?: any): Observable<IResponse> {

    return this.http.delete(url, params)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json() as IResponse)
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

You'll notice that I've also created an interface which types up my response from the backend, which is usually something like:

```
{error: any; data: any; results: number; total: number;}
```

Now that we've taken care of those problems, let's tackle your original question. The most likely reason as to why your request isn't running, is that you're not subscribing to the `http` observable. Observables are lazy so if you don't subscribe to it via `.subscribe` or `@ngrx/effects`, it just won't do anything.

So let's assume that you're calling `CreateGroup` like this:

```
this.groupsService.CreateGroup(data);
```

This won't do anything until you subscribe:

```
this.groupsService.CreateGroup(data).subscribe(() => {

  // Here you can react to the post, close a modal, redirect or whatever you want.
});
```

I'd also recommend adding a `.first()` to your api calls as this will prevent you from having to unsubscribe from the observables manually when the component is destroyed.

So to use the implementation as above you'd simply do:

```
constructor(private appApi: AppApi) {}

...

this.appApi.post('/groups').first().subscribe(() => {

  // Do something
});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. i can do refactoring later once existing code start working. can you see any issue with existing code and why my post call isn't firing at all?

Comment: @jatin can you share the code where you use these methods in your injectable?

Answer (score 1):

Don't stringify the POST data in HTTP POST. Simply pass the object.